# Were Sihon and Og related?

Tags: numbers, deuteronomy

The Bible tends to pair these two individuals, even if they were different individuals. So did they share something in common (i.e. being Nephilim)? Were they major allies?

> "We have heard how the Lord dried up the water of the Red Sea[a] for you when you came out of Egypt, and what you did to Sihon and Og, the two kings of the Amorites east of the Jordan, whom you completely destroyed."- **Joshua 2:10**

Even the Canaanites appear to pair Sihon and Og.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bible there isn’t a genealogy of the Amorite King’s to determine their relations. We do have passages like

> and all that he did to the A**two kings of the Amorites**, that were beyond the Jordan, to Sihon king of Heshbon, and to Og king of Bashan, who was at Ashtaroth. Joshua 9:10

Therefore we can conclude that both locations were of Amorite descent.

It would be reasonable to assume that a region had a king over them that was of their own nationality or from the same ancestor but just like the queen of England is German descent ruling over the British it’s possible to have a king not of the same descent. Much rarer in antiquity but not unheard of, for instance the Pharaoh at the time of Israel’s slavery in Egypt was an Assyrian ruling over Egypt.

> For thus saith the Lord Jehovah, My people went down at the first into Egypt to sojourn there: and the Assyrian hath oppressed them without cause. Isaiah 52:4

In the event that the two kings were Amorites then at some point they would be related but how far removed is not something one can determine from the Bible alone.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Evil Among the Nations**

Kabbalah explains why we were told to eradicate only 7 of the 10 evil nations.  Advanced
From the teachings of Rabbi Yitzchak Luria; translated and edited by Moshe Yaakov Wisnefsky

https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379644/jewish/Evil-Among-the-Nations.htm

> ...In the portion of the Torah read this week, Moses reviews the
>   journeys on which he led the Jewish people on their way to the
>   threshold of the Land of Israel. They were told by G‑d not to wage war
>   against the descendents of Esau, who inhabited Mt. Seir (ibid. 2:2-8)
>   or to wage war against Moab (ibid. 2:9) or Ammon. (ibid. 2:17-19) In
>   contrast, they were commanded to fight and conquer the two Amorite
>   kings, Sichon (ibid. 2:24-25,31) and Og (ibid. 3:2).
>
> ...Thus, the two Amorite kings, Sichon and Og, personify the two
>   layers covering the sefira of yesod that must be eliminated in order
>   for the Jewish people (and each individual Jew) to reveal their innate
>   sensitivity to each other as well as to G‑d, and thus be prepared to
>   enter the holy Land of Israel.

2. **"The Aegean Ogygos of Boeotia and the Biblical Og of Bashan:
   Reflections of the Same Myth."**
   First Published in: Zeitschrlft fur die alttestamentliche Wissenschaft 110 (1998), 411-426.

PDF: http://faculty.washington.edu/snoegel/PDFs/articles/Noegel%2025%20-%20ZaW%201998.pdf

Excerpt p. 424. The article involves Biblical mythology which was quite interesting.

[image: book]

Comment: Interesting that the Israelites viewed Sihon and Og as extremely demonic beings.